# convert log format w3c to NCSA for goaccess

Tags: log-analysis, goaccess

I tried to analyze a file `/usr/local/cpanel/logs/access_log` using `goaccess` but goaccess could not parse the log format of that file.

Is there any way to convert log format in that file to a format `goaccess` can analyze?

The file `access_log` has contents

```
165.112.33.14 - root [02/21/2023:18:30:05 -0000] "GET /cpsess3054144762/json-api/loadavg HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "example.hostname.com:2087" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:100.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/100.0" "s" "-" 2087
```

I think it should be changed to a format that `goaccess` can parse, for example

```
165.112.33.14 - - [22/Feb/2023:11:10:18 +0200] "GET /img/img12.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 - "example.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0"
```

Comment: Can you provide an example snippet of the `access_log` you have, and an example of what you want it to look like?

Comment: what I have is:
165.112.33.14 - root [02/21/2023:18:30:05 -0000] "GET /cpsess3054144762/json-api/loadavg HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://example.hostname.com:2087/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:100.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/100.0" "s" "-" 2087


what I want is:
165.112.33.14 - - [22/Feb/2023:11:10:18 +0200] "GET /img/img12.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 - "https://example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0"